# Bash: get date and time from another time zone

Tags: bash, date, timezone

I would want to get the date and time from another time zone (UTC-4) with a bash command, but I don't want to configure it as the default TZ for the system.

Is there a simple way to do it? 

E.g 1 (current):

```
$ date
fri nov  7 13:15:35 UTC 2014
```

E.g 2 (what I need):

```
$ date (+ some option for UTC-4)
fri nov  7 09:15:35 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use

```
TZ=America/New_York date
```

or if you want to do date arithmetic you could use

```
date -d "+5 hours"
```

Comment: Thank you @almas shaikh, the first option is the most accurate response for my case.

Comment: But it requires you to know the proper name of the time zone you want, which can be tricky to find out sometimes.  You can also use a numeric offset, though it's by no means obvious how.  The [timezone(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timezone) manual page has the gory details.

Comment: Also maybe check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to find e.g. that `TZ=Asia/Kolkata` is one way to get IST (which is tricky because `TZ=UTC-5:30` isn't entirely obvious; e.g. `UTC-5.5` doesn't work).

Comment: Any way this could be achieved for macOS? `-d` argument is for `daylight saving offset` in the date tool and there is no argument for date string.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac OS. This `TZ=UTC date -R` does work though.

Comment: For time zones with hours and minutes + or - UTC, eg for India: `date -d "+5 hours 30 minutes"`

Answer (score 13):

You can use offset value in `TZ` to get the date for a different timezone:

```
TZ=UTC date -R
Fri, 07 Nov 2014 13:55:07 +0000

TZ=UTC+4 date -R
Fri, 07 Nov 2014 09:54:52 -0400
```

Comment: Yes that is how `TZ` works with offset. I would suggest using offset since it doesn't require you to remember long & valid timezone names.

Comment: You don't need a subshell.  `TZ=UTC date` sets `TZ`, runs `date`, and reverts the value of `TZ` to its previous value (unset, or different value, or the same value as the one you specified, as the case may be).

Comment: Also, `TZ=UTC-4 date` confusingly prints the time zone as "UTC" even though it's not.  (This is visible in your example output, too.)

Comment: Also better to use `date -R` for `--rfc-2822` format which displays correct offset as well.

Comment: The `TZ=UTC date -R` is the only solution I could get to work that works on Mac OS for a redis set key insert I am doing and wanted UTC: `redis-cli set starttime "$(TZ=UTC date -R)"`

Answer (score 8):

I use a little script for that, so I don't have to know or remember the exact name of the timezone I'm looking for. The script takes a search string as argument, and gives the date and time for any timezone matching the search. I named it `wdate`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Show date and time in other time zones

search=$1

format='%a %F %T %z'
zoneinfo=/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/

if command -v timedatectl >/dev/null; then
    tzlist=$(timedatectl list-timezones)
else
    tzlist=$(find -L $zoneinfo -type f -printf "%P\n")
fi

grep -i "$search" <<< "$tzlist" \
| while read z
  do
      d=$(TZ=$z date +"$format")
      printf "%-32s %s\n" "$z" "$d"
  done
```

Example output:

```
$ wdate fax
America/Halifax                  Fri 2022-03-25 09:59:02 -0300
```

or

```
$ wdate canad
Canada/Atlantic                  Fri 2022-03-25 10:00:04 -0300
Canada/Central                   Fri 2022-03-25 08:00:04 -0500
Canada/Eastern                   Fri 2022-03-25 09:00:04 -0400
Canada/Mountain                  Fri 2022-03-25 07:00:04 -0600
Canada/Newfoundland              Fri 2022-03-25 10:30:04 -0230
Canada/Pacific                   Fri 2022-03-25 06:00:04 -0700
Canada/Saskatchewan              Fri 2022-03-25 07:00:04 -0600
Canada/Yukon                     Fri 2022-03-25 06:00:04 -0700
```

Answer (score 4):

If the other solutioons don't work, use

```
date --date='TZ="UTC+4" 2016-08-22 10:37:44' "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

> 2016-08-22 16:37:44

Answer (score 0):

You may also add minutes using the following for Time Zones with half an hour difference:

```
date -d "-210 mins"
```