# bash: convert hw timestamps to human and offset timezone

Tags: bash, datetime, timezone-offset

I have a script that reads files with linux timestamps and I'd like to convert them to human format while keeping the timezone offsets.

Script:

```
[..]
UPTIME=$(cut -d" " -f1 < /proc/uptime)
SECONDS=$(date +%s)
date -d"70-1-1 + $SECONDS sec - $UPTIME sec + $TIMESTAMP sec "   +"%d/%m/%Y %T"
[..]
```

The problem is that I have a +2h timezone offset, so that my script shows dates early by 2hours

```
date "+%z %Z"
+0200 IST
```

How can I adjust the script to use the timezone offset?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: get date and time from another time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802201/bash-get-date-and-time-from-another-time-zone)

Comment: I currently solved via `date -d"$(date -d"70-1-1 + $SECONDS sec - $UPTIME sec + $TIMESTAMP sec" +"%d/%m/%Y %T") $(date +%z) hours" +"%d/%m/%Y %T"` - thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date` with `-u` parameter which according to the manual it displays the output in UTC.