# How to set current date as git commit message with time zone?

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-commit

`git commit -m "$(date)"`   ->  is displaying in UTC, but how to get preferred time zone?

I wanted to get preferred timezone in `git commit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: get date and time from another time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802201/bash-get-date-and-time-from-another-time-zone)

Answer (score 3):

Strange, considering I always see my commits using my local timezone.
Meaning you do not need to include `date` output in the commit message itself.

But you can set the [`TZ` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561581/6309) to benefit from a display using your timezone.

> ```
> export TZ=CET
> git show -s --format=%cd --date=iso-local
> ```

That will show the date of your last commit. In CET timezone.

date inside the commit message:

```
git commit -m "$(date -d 'TZ="Australia/Sydney"')"
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2024-02-23**

Suggested action is not maintained anymore. I've made a fork and will keep it up-to-date.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/timezoneaction

```
uses: MathRobin/timezone-action@v1.1
with:
  timezoneLinux: 'Asia/Singapore'
  timezoneMacos: 'Europe/Paris'
  timezoneWindows: 'W. Central Africa Standard Time'
```

Fully compatible with previous package.

Action from szenius is using node 16 which is deprecated and will not be usable during Spring 2024: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/

> Our plan is to transition all actions to run on Node 20 by Spring
> 2024.

---

**Older deprecated solution**

You can use the [Set Timezone](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-timezone) GH Action. This action will set the specified timezone for your GH Runner's machine.

For example:

```
uses: szenius/set-timezone@v1.1
with:
  timezoneLinux: "Asia/Singapore"
  timezoneMacos: "Asia/Singapore"
  timezoneWindows: "Singapore Standard Time"
```

Under the hood, it uses the `timedatectl` (Linux), `timezoneMacos` (MacOS), or `timezoneWindows` (Windows) tool to set a timezone depending on your job environment.

This Action should be placed before executing the `git commit` command and within a single job.